# SharePoint Object Model UserProfileManager Exception: "the value's length for key 'application name' exceeds its limit of '128'."

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-userprofile

When trying to retrieve user profiles using SharePoint Object model it gives the 
"the value's length for key 'application name' exceeds its limit of '128'."  Apparently the solution is to reduce the length of the UserProfle DB Name. It is not possible for the environment I am working and is there any possible way to solve this exception without changing the DB name?

Answer (score 0):

This can be resolved by reducing the namespace length of the dll.